# Change Icon of Running Application via NSRunningApplication? What's the setter?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm new to this objective-c (1 week)

What is the setter called for the `icon` property via `NSRunningApplication`?
Where can i find this in the docs just for my future reference so everytime i need to learn a setter i dont have to ask. :)

I noticed in docs `[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] icon]` is a property. Is it possible to set this icon property? Will it change the icon used in dock and the mini icon shown in the minimized window? I point out the mini icon in minimized windows in this image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setter. The `icon` property of `NSRunningApplication` is `readonly`.

`NSRunningApplication` can *sometimes* refer to the current application, but it's more general than that. It can also refer to other applications on the system. It wouldn't be alright for any application to be able to set the icon of any other application, would it?

Anyway, you want to be working with the main application object of the process, which is the instance of `NSApplication`. You can get access to that object using `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`. You can also use the global variable `NSApp`.

`NSApplication` has an `applicationIconImage` property that's read-write. Setting that is the easiest way to change the application's icon.

Alternatively, you can obtain the application's dock tile object (an instance of `NSDockTile`) using the `dockTile` property. You can then set a custom view for the dock tile's `contentView` and that view can render however you want it to. (You can use an `NSImageView` if you just want to display an image.)

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches will change the badge on the icons of minimized windows (although the class overview docs for `NSDockTile` say it will). There's not a direct way to do that. You can obtain the dock tile of a minimized window and set a custom view, but then you're responsible for drawing everything about it. There's no way to *just* change or replace the badge part.

Comment: Thanks Ken you have such awesome replies! In that screenshot above i did use `setApplicationIconImage` to make it that golden globe. True its not right for other apps to set others icons, i was hoping to do it from within the application though. I'm making a firefox addon :) I was able to get the mini win mini icon to change but i had to create an alias file to all the files in the original app except the icon which i replaced. But the issue with that is, do you think this is the only way? Other then getting mini window drawing and badging it myself. Thanks so much!

Comment: With the copy to `.app` as alias's except icon. If the application is running and i change the icon in the `.app` then do `killall Dock;` it updates both icons however it unminimizes the minimized windows. Do you know what `killall Dock` is doing so I can make it update the icons without destroying and redrawing everything haha? Thanks man you really spoon feed the newbs thank you!! :D I'm stuck on that image convert thing to icns but it's going to get done and then I'll share :) I just have to figure out some stuff :)

Comment: Btw about `applicationIconImage` being read-write does it show in the docs? and does it show the setter name? Cuz I only knew that one from github code searches.

Comment: Don't kill the Dock. `killall Dock` sends a `SIGTERM` signal to all of your processes whose executables are named "Dock". By default, a process which receives a `SIGTERM` signal terminates. That's what's happening to the Dock. Then, `launchd` restarts it automatically, but that does things like unminimizes windows.

Comment: The docs for `applicationIconImage` are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSApplication/applicationIconImage). It doesn't show as `readonly`, which means that it's read-write by default. It doesn't specify a setter name, so it gets the default which is the property name, capitalized, with "set" prepended to it, and (in Objective-C) a colon appended to it. So: `setApplicationIconImage:`.

Comment: Thanks Ken! Check out this code though: [GithubGIST ::  Noitidart / chromium_dock.mm #L127](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/c666f9b7056f4feab33e#file-chromium_dock-mm-L127) I got it out of google chrome's code. Do you think this would allow us to update the icon while maintaining same position? I'm not so good at reading objc yet but hope to convert this to ctypes as I learn. :)

Comment: Personally, I would not ship a product that killed the Dock, no matter the purpose. And if I noticed a third-party app doing that, I would trash it. File a bug with Apple. Cite the `NSDockTile` docs which say this should work: "A window Dock tile defaults to display a miniaturized version of the windows contents with a badge derived from the application Dock icon, **including any customized application Dock icon**." Then, open a Developer Technical Support incident referencing that bug and asking for a workaround.

Comment: Hey Ken by any chance would you be able to help me file the Dev Tech Support, I understand if it's no. It's just it looks like I need membership. I'm doing open source free stuff cuz i cant get those subscription fees filled. I created the bug though, the id is 19559583 i dont know how to link it though. If you can't though i toalllly understand. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. Bug reports are private between the filer and Apple. Others can't view them. I realize that not everybody can afford a membership. Are you a student? I believe Apple offers discounted memberships.

Comment: Thanks man no problem I totally understand. I checked for student program I don't think they have one :( only for iOS :( https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/ and its just free for University's (who have all the money after straddling students for money insane man how the world works lol anyways enough of that rant :P )

Comment: So now dont do that `killall Dock` but instead right click and say "Keep in dock" this forces update on dock icon. Then unmini and remini to get icon update on mini win. Do you know whats programatically going on in the "keep in dock" and "unmini remini", whatever its doing is forcing update, maybe I can just execute that! Plz advise! :)

Comment: Oh wow actually i dont even have to make it a full copy of app to my own app as .alias. I can just make a .app with shell script that launches that firefox, i just tell it to hide the firefox icon with LSUIcon. The "Keep on dock" updates the icon on the dock and unminimize and re-minimize updates the icon. Yeah man! if you can just help figure out how to programtically execute the part of the code that updates the mini window icon and dock via unminmize/reminimize and "keep on dock" that would be fantastic!!!! man super excited! :D im so close!!